# Checking a datagrid item as a numeric

Tags: c#, windows, forms, types, row

I am trying to get a datagrid to display different colour rows based on the quantity of the item.

The problem I'm having is the if statement:

```
if (RowType == < 5)
```

is invalid, how do I parse the row type to be checked against a value?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtaPart.Rows)
{
    //Cell three is where quantity is 
    string RowType = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

    if (RowType ==  //> 5)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
    else if (RowType == //< 5)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
    else if (RowType == //< 1)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `double value = double.Parse(RowType)` then check if `value > 5, < 5, < 1` etc.

However, if your datagrid column already contains a numeric type, like `double` or `int`, you don't need to call `ToString()` and then parse the string; So instead of this:

```
string RowTypeStr = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString(); 
double RowType = double.Parse(RowTypeStr);
```

but you can directly cast the value:

```
double RowType = (double)row.Cells[3].Value;
```